# Determining "hidden" values in nodes

Tags: node-editor

Assume you have a colour mix node that you are using to determine the roughness value of a Glossy BSDF. Is there any way to actually see the roughness value?
 Is there a way to see set values of nodes in general, if they are not set "in place"?

Comment: AFAIK you can't :( all you can do is preview the value (0<value<1) with an emission shader, but nothing accurate...

Comment: I like to plug values into an emission shader to visualize them in the viewport.  if I understand your question correctly I think that is as close as you can get.

Answer (score 3):

**Plainly as a number, no.  Approximately, yes.**

You can plug anything into the color input of an emission node and plug that into the surface material output.  This will let you visualize the values across the mesh in the viewport with rendered viewport mode.

There is a handy addon written by Greg Zaal, called [node wrangler](http://adaptivesamples.com/node-wrangler-update/), which (along with a billion other useful things) will do this automatically by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> (left clicking) on a node.

To make numerical values easier to distinguish you can plug the value into a color ramp node first, then you can create a colorful gradient in the color ramp which will make it easier to see the value in the viewport.

Comment: It would be good to have some kind of "probe" node to display values. The values exist and must be assigned somewhere and I bet a python script can do this.

Comment: @PatHertel Yes it would, but the problem is that often the value of a property will vary at each point on the mesh, which isn't really feasible to display in any way other than as a color.

Comment: @PatHertel Holding the left mouse button over whatever part of the mesh you're interested in in the rendered image shows you the RGBA values (among other things). This could be problematic if the values you want are above 1.0 or below 0.0 though - I never tried if Blender retains such "impossible" colours.

Comment: @MartinSojka Blender will keep RGB values greater than 1, they are in fact quite useful in the compositor.

Comment: @PGmath Yeah, I just checked with a quick node setup (Geometry's *Position* output to Emission's *Color* input) - Blender also happily keeps and shows you negative RGB values in the rendered image (... or *any* image, for that matter).