# Getting the actual (not default) value of a node socket that is linked to another socket

Tags: python, materials, node-editor

I know how to get the `default_value` from a node socket as described in this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77335/20051).  But the answer there doesn't answer the question, namely: how to get the *actual* computed value of a socket.

How can I get the actual value using python?

[image: example node structure]

For example, how would I determine the final `Roughness` value in this node structure assuming the value is constant for the material?

(I'm thinking this is not possible in general since it wouldn't work for values that change over the model, e.g., trying to obtain the `Pointiness` value from a `Geometry` node, which isn't a constant.)

Comment: As a workaround, [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27146/20051) is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this cannot be done easily. The reason is:

- The shader node tree is `compiled` by cycles in SVM or OCL. And here the actual calculation takes place.
- Also every sample in Cycles can potentially have a different Roughness (for example when connected to a TextureImage along the way). So which sample do you want the result from.

If you have a special case you can mimic the needed nodes in python and evaluate for your needs.

Comment: If not as a value, can the result of the shader node tree be baked to an image? E.g. would it be possible to implement an exporter that creates a roughness texture from arbitrary node inputs?